# How do i shorten a if statement in that situation?

Tags: php

I'm doing an if statement to check if a certain value is in an array

```
    if ((!in_array($add['job_type'][$key], $jobtypes))) {
        $add['job_type'][$key] = NULL;
    }
```

I did multiple if statements to do the same thing, but i want to do something like this, to put my code smaller and easy to read:

```
    $value   = ($value == '0') ? $value = NULL : $value;
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Your first code block is probably better off kept as it is. Turning it into a ternary statement would probably make it more complicated and harder to read.

Comment: Agreed. The ternary is not so bad with simple variables, but when it's a multidimensional array reference, you'll have to repeat that complex expression.

Comment: @MarkM Agreed, less lines is not necessarily clearer code.

Comment: FYI, the correct way to write the second code is: `$value = ($value == '0') ? NULL : $value;`.

Comment: For future reference, though, here's the docs on the ternary operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @Barmar i use `$foo = $maybeunsetvar ?: NULL;` so $foo is either $maybeunsetvar or NULL, but never undefined. am i wrong?

Comment: you have one set of extra `()` in your code too.

Comment: @r3wt That works if you're just testing whether the variable is unset. But he's testing whether it's equal to a specific string `'0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the *length* of the `if` statement is your problem if your code is unreadable.  I would suspect it's actually because:

> I did multiple if statements to do the same thing

Instead of manually specifying multiple `if` statements, you can make this a function:

```
function updateJobType($key) {
  if ((!in_array($add['job_type'][$key], $jobtypes))) {
    $add['job_type'][$key] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Then invoke it with whichever arguments you like:

```
updateJobType('job1');
updateJobType('job2');
updateJobType('job3');
```

That said, it's a bit hard to tell without the full context of the problem, or your full code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but wouldn't this work ...

```
$add['job_type'][$key] = (in_array($add['job_type'][$key], $jobtypes)) ?  $add['job_type'][$key] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do the first block is:

```php
$add['job_type'][$key] = (in_array($add['job_type'][$key], $jobtypes)) ? : NULL;
```

But if you have a lot of code doing the same thing with a lot of other arrays, you need to write a function (or method). Now you will have:

```php
function unsetVar(&$value, &$arr){
    $value = (in_array($value, $arr)) ? : NULL;
}
```

Then, call the function this way:

```php
unsetVar($add['job_type'][$key], $jobtypes);
```